# Raphael: Adding Multiple Paths on Array Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

I'm using Raphael. I'm trying to have two separate svg paths on my array options (wheel.people and wheel.leadEntrepreneur) so that I can style them differently. So in essence I want to add another path alongside the one that exists. One is for an svg shape and the other will be for an svg icon. I have managed to construct the shapes using the code below but now need to overlay the icons on top of the shapes. So How do I create an additional path for the icons and apply different styling?

```
var R = Raphael("paper", 400, 400);

var attr = {
    fill: "#333",
    stroke: "#fff",
    "stroke-width": 1,
    "stroke-linejoin": "round",
    cursor: "pointer"
};

var wheel = {};
wheel.people = R.path("M205.1,84.2c-0.8-0.4-1.6-0.7-2.5-1.1c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2c-5.4-2.2-11-3.9-16.6-5 c-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1c-5.7-1.1-11.5-1.7-17.3-1.7h-0.5c-4.7,0-9.4,0.4-14,1.1l-4.7-6.5l-0.8-1.1v0l-40.8-57 c9.1-3.5,18.4-6.2,27.9-8.1c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.1c10.5-2.1,21.2-3.1,31.9-3.1h0.5c10.7,0,21.4,1.1,31.9,3.1 c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.1c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.1,1,0.2l3.6,72v0l0.1,1.2v0L205.1,84.2z").attr(attr);
wheel.leadEntrepreneur = R.path("M285,50l-0.3,0.6l-35.6,62l-0.6,1l-3.3,5.8c-0.5-0.8-1-1.7-1.6-2.5c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.4 c-3.2-4.7-6.9-9.2-11-13.4c0,0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.3c-4.2-4.1-8.7-7.8-13.4-11c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3 c-4.1-2.7-8.5-5.1-12.9-7.1l-0.3-6.2v0l-0.1-1.2v0l-3.6-72c10.1,2.1,20.1,5.1,29.7,9.1c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.2 c9.8,4.1,19.3,9.1,28.3,15.1c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.3c8.7,5.9,17,12.7,24.8,20.4C284.8,49.8,284.9,49.9,285,50L285,50z").attr(attr);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by your 'array options' and what you mean by 'on top'..on top of what ?

Comment: The different options: wheel.people and wheel.leadEntrepreneur
On Top: On top of the shapes represented by "people" and "leadEntrepreneur"

Comment: I still have no idea, you have an object with 2 elements. Are there, or is that it ? Maybe put them on a fiddle and state what isn't working. If you just want different styles, you can have either attr = {somestyling} and attr2 = { some other styling} and apply the respective object as styling. Or you can do it as css by giving them an id or something. Maybe you mean that ?

Comment: I guess I want two different paths on an object each with different styling.

Comment: just use path1.attr( attr1 ) and path2.attr( attr2 ) and create attr1 & 2 styling objects like you already have.

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/da771pyy/ Could you post the solution so I can accept it?